# Need historical address information

Tags: addresses

I inadvertently changed an address on a contact and need to change it back to it's previous address.  How do I find historical address information?

Answer (score 4):

This is only possible if you have "detailed logging" enabled.  If not, you'll need to restore a backup copy of your database (to a test server!) and do a comparison.

You can check to see if you have detailed logging enabled at **Administer menu » System Settings » Misc**, under Logging (see screenshot).  If you do NOT have this enabled, please read the [logging documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/initial-set-up/change-logging/) before enabling it.  If you have shared hosting, you may not be allowed to turn this on; if you run CiviCRM on your own server or VPS, then you should have no problem.
[image]

If you DO have detailed logging enabled:

- Go to the contact record with the changed address.
- Click the **Change Log** tab.
- Find the change that corresponds to the date that the address was changed and click **Update** next to it.
- You should see before-and-after results.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I agree with Jon, but be careful as enabling detail logging  can significantly increase the size of your database over time.  You'll want to ensure you have enough storage.

Answer (score 2):

We sometimes use a custom location type "Old address", so when we add a new address we set the previous as "Old address" and the new one as the "Home" + primary. Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Dropdown Options > Location Types (Home, Work...).

Answer (score 2):

I think this extension will help you for the future record.

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/formercommunicationdata

Comment: Yes it will help for all changes to address etc which have not happened yet. ie it only generates info for changes made after installing the extension. for ones that may have already happened and are in you log_ tables, you probably need to try Advanced Report (though it didn't fire up for my first effort)

Answer (score 1):

Might also want to consider using the "Future address changes" extension, https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.futureaddress

Future address changes
This extensions adds functionality to change an address in the future, the old address is archived as an activity in civicrm.

Answer (score 0):

Wikimedia use the Advanced Report extension to provide a tab showing address history (rendering a report as a tab is an extended reports feature) (citing https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1021#note_18644)